# operands could not be broadcast together with shapes

Tags: deep-learning, som

I have used this code but it showing me error. Help me solve this.

```
som=MiniSom(x=10,y=10,input_len=15,sigma=1.0,learning_rate=0.5)
som.random_weights_init(x)

som.train_random(data=x,num_iteration=100)

from pylab import bone, pcolor, colorbar, plot, show
bone()

pcolor(som.distance_map().T)

colorbar()

markers = ['o', 's']
colors = ['r', 'g']

for i, x1 in enumerate(x):
    w = som.winner(x)
    plot(w[0] + 0.5,
         w[1] + 0.5,
         markers[y[i]],
         markeredgecolor = colors[y[i]],
         markerfacecolor = 'None',
         markersize = 10,
         markeredgewidth = 2)

show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The line `w = som.winner(x)` should be replaced with `w = som.winner(x1)`

`MiniSom.winner()` method computes the coordinates of the winning neuron for the sample x, where sample x is **one single row** of your dataset, and the corresponding variable name in your code is **x1**.

You are iterating `x1` over rows of x, however still trying to use the dataset variable **x** with `som.winner()` method.